# WPF ValidationRule when control IsEnabled=false

Tags: wpf, validation

how do I add a ValidationRule to my control that **only** fires when the control is enabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx), look under the 'Custom validation rules' and you could check it in the   `public override ValidationResult Validate` method.

Just do

```
if (mytextbox.IsEnabled) {// validate here}
```

EDIT:

So, instead of doing your validation rule binding in XAML, I think you'll need to do it in your code behind, and there you can assign a property you've created in your custom validation rule class to your current instance of your combobox, and then use that in your override of your `Validate` method.

So in your validationrule class

```
public ComboBox MyCombo
{
     get;
     set;
}
```

then when doing your validation rule binding

```
myvalidationinstance.MyCombo = mycombobox;
```

now you can use your `MyCombo` property in the Validate method to check `IsEnabled`

Comment: OK, so I've got a validationRule on the ComboBox's SelectedValue property to check if the value is null.

How do I get a handle on the control itself in the validationRule. As far as I can see you just have the value object which, in my case, is going to be the SelectedValue. 

Thanks

Comment: I see what you mean. Didn't think of doing the binding in code.

Thanks for your reply.